# Impact of denied entry to Croatia on trying to enter a Schengen country with a valid visa

Tags: schengen-visas, spain, denial-of-entry

Last year I was not allowed to continue my trip to Croatia due to having only single entry Schengen visa. However when I was refused entry to Croatia the border guard from the Croatia side did not stamp anything nor give me a letter. I was however not allowed to go in, and they just asked me to go back to Slovenia and enjoy my holiday elsewhere in a Schengen  country.

Question is now I got a valid multiple entry Schengen visa from the Spanish embassy in Buenos Aires will I be turned away at the border?

My concern is due to being denied entry from Croatia will I be recorded in the sis system? Even though at that time the Croatian  border guard did not stamp any cancellation stamp, or ask me to sign any letter. The guard even said to just apply for a Croatian visa in Ljubljana if you wish or travel to Venice since it is in the Schengen area.

My concern was not allowed to enter Spain despite valid visa due to being denied entry from Croatia in last years trip.

Comment: Are you asking if you will be turned away from the Spanish boarder, or if you go back to Croatia? You have a visa allowing you entry Schengen  countries (this means Spain is fine), if you want to go to Croatia then simply apply for a visa and you will be granted entry.

Comment: @Uciebila thank you for your reply my concerned is will i be turned  away at the spanish border only despite having valid visa will it most like to happen?

Comment: Why i am i afraid because at 2018 i waz denied entry to croatia due to single entrance schengen visa.

Answer (score 3):

No, you're good for the Schengen states with your current visa. You can even enter Croatia on it since it's a multi visa.

Comment: Crazydre thank you so much for yor answer and the information really appreciate it .

Answer (score 2):

For [Croatia](http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/) (and possibly Albania and North Macedonia) a **single** Schengen Visa C is **not** a valid visa

- because it does not insure that you can return to the Schengen area

that was why you were refused entry and sent back to Slovenia.

Slovenia should have cancelled their Schengen exit stamp.

Legally you did not leave the Schengen area during this process.

There should be no negative SIS entry for that trip.

The fact that you now have had a new visa issued is also a sign that your travel history is ok.

This should not cause any problems on reentry.

Comment: Returning to the Schengen area is usually not a reason. It is that the Schengen countries check the visitors and if they trust that person for more than one visit, Croatia does not bother to check them again.

Comment: Thanks alot mark for your  answer oh yeah i forgot to tell you the slovenian border guard voided my exit with two paralel linws at the exit stamp , however when boarding a plane from ljubjana to amsterdam and amsterdam to athens i was asked weather i have visa  or not and explain the whole situation to the airline check in crew but no questions when leaving the schengen area via switzerland or when i checked in from athens to zurich they jusg greated me witg a big smile.

Comment: Willeke thank you so much for the additional info and your comment as well.